# Installing Qt on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012

How do I do that? I can't find any tutorial describing this. Well, I've downloaded win7 64bit version of Qt 5, I installed this (more than 1gb, wow...). However, I still cannot include any Qt library.

`#include <QApplication>` displays - cannot open source blah blah blah.

What else should I do, am I missing something here?

---

Another thing is - won't this 1gb Qt thing slow down my application? I'm not writing any big projects, just simple algorithms, cpp files usually don't go more than 20kb.

---

And one more - what does nokia has to do with Qt? I've already seen a couple of times the nokia company name while I was reading something about the Qt.

Answer (score 0):

> What else should I do, am I missing something here?

Install qt vs addin v 1.2.x

> Another thing is - won't this 1gb Qt thing slow down my application?

Nope. Why do you think, that data stored on your drive will slowdown your programs? Your music / video will not, same qt libraries.

Btw, Qt runtime is quiet small (about 4 mb for simple GUI applications).

> what does nokia has to do with Qt?

Nokia bought Trolltech with qt for their mobile platforms. And now it sells qt to Digia.

Feel free to use google ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also check that all the Qt includes should be accessible/visible for Visual Studio after installation, like probably through PATH environment variable.